# Renaming Column Values Efficiently

Tags: r, rstudio, data-manipulation, data-cleaning, renaming

I am trying to rename values in my data all at once, rather than doing it entry by entry.

Right now I am using this code to perform my changes:

```
INV$Classification[INV$Classification=="lay net"] <- "Illegal Lay Net"
```

My data is INV, and my column is Classification. I want to find all instances of the words "lay net" and replace them with "Illegal Lay Net". I am doing this manually right now, which I could ultimately do in excel. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

For Example I have entries such as: POSSIBLE ILLEGAL LAY NET or Lay Nets Violation, these do not get picked up by just using the "lay net" find and thus are not switched because this code is very specific.

Comment: What software are you trying to use? This sounds like a simple find and replace, which the [Knuth-Morris-Pratt algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) is great at (for finding matches). Replacing text will be very dependent of the technology you are using to do it (use Ctrl+F and use the Replace options in Excel - if that's your platform, then this question belongs on SuperUser and is definitely a duplicate).

Comment: I am using RStudio, I would love for it to be a very simple find and replace but have not found any code that seems to work.

Comment: Please, you need to tag your post with things like that which are highly-relevant.

Comment: It looks like you might be running into case-sensitivity issues too (i.e. "AbcD" is treated differently as "aBCd"). You can usually get around this by putting your string to search through an uppercase or lowercase function first, so for example if you are searching for "abcd" then do `UPPER(MyVariable).Contains(UPPER(MySearch))` (pseudocode).

Comment: I am sorry, this is my first time posting. I am not sure I understand, is this separate from creating a string in stringr?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to start using regular expressions.  Take a look at `gsub`, `grep`, `grepl` and similar functions.  Of course it is not a magic bullet, you still have to understand and make sure you catch every case.

Here is an example that will catch the 3 cases you said:

```
INV$Classification[grepl("lay net", INV$Classification, ignore.case=T)] <- "Illegal Lay Net"
```

Comment: This worked so awesome! Thank you! So much faster than doing it one at a time

Answer (score 0):

Here's a verbose tidyverse solution using stringr, first converting to lowercase and then testing if that includes "lay net," replacing with the new string if it does.

```
library(tidyverse)
INV <- INV %>% 
  mutate(Classification = if_else(Classification %>% 
                                  tolower %>% 
                                  str_detect("lay net"),
                                  "Illegal Lay Net", Classification)
```